# Set every odd element of a non-empty list of integers to zero

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried using boolean but not working

```
a = [4,10,1,7]

if a % 2 != 0:
    print a
```

all I get in the terminal is `unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'`

How to get an output of `[4,10,0,0]`

Comment: `[0 if x%2 else x for x in a]`

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you are not iterating of `a`. Iterate through the list then check with your `if` condition, it's met then apply then changes:

```
a = [4,10,1,7]

for i, x in enumerate(a):

    if x % 2 != 0:
        a[i] = 0
print a
[4, 10, 0, 0]
```

Alternatively, you can do it with a built-in methods, like `map`:

```
a = map(lambda x: 0 if x%2 else x, a)
```

Or through list comprehension, like [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) comment:

```
a = [0 if x%2 else x for x in a]
```

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate):

> `enumerate(sequence, start=0)` Return an enumerate object. sequence must
>   be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports
>   iteration. The next() method of the iterator returned by enumerate()
>   returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0)
>   and the values obtained from iterating over sequence.
>
> ```
> >>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
> >>> list(enumerate(seasons)) [(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
> >>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1)) [(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
> ```

Comment: just wondering what difference with a list index and list elements?

Comment: @DeclanLunney..Check the update for more clarification, `a` is a list of elements...`4,10,1,7` are elements of `a` list and `0,1,2,3` are indexes of the elements respectively...so element 4 has index 0, element 10 has index 1, element 1 has index 2 and element 7 has index 3. List indexing always starts from 0, but in enumerate you can choose from where to start.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to iterate over the elements (preferably with a for loop since you know the number of elements in the list):

```
for n in range(len(a)):
```

Then, for each element check if it is an even or odd number:

```
if a[n] % 2 != 0:
    a[n] = 0
```